# Swipe up/down to control audio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to control audio volume how VLC media player does on android. Here's an example of how it works.

[image]

However I'm not sure about the math, here's what I've tried

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    int volume_level= audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int max_volume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int changeVolumeBy = volume_level;
    int movement = (int) (e1.getY() - e2.getY());
    if ((Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY())) > 100) {

        if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {
                // down
            changeVolumeBy = Math.abs((Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / movement));
        } else if ((e1.getY() > e2.getY())) {
            // up
            changeVolumeBy = (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels  / movement);
        }

        if (changeVolumeBy > max_volume) {
            changeVolumeBy = max_volume;
        } else if (changeVolumeBy < 0) {
            changeVolumeBy = 0;
        }
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, changeVolumeBy, 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is the volume doesn't change linearly, it peaks and isn't very reliable.

My question: Am I using the appropriate method for this or is there a flaw in the way I'm doing it?

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: I've added the question